# Need PS Get-Childitem to not truncate name results

Tags: powershell

This is what I'm running:

```
Get-Childitem $("C:\Powershell Tests\Group 1") -Recurse -Force | where { -not$_.PSIsContainer } | group name -NoElement | sort name  > "C:\Powershell Tests\Group 1.txt"
```

I'm later using this text file and comparing with the names in another to see what he differences are between the two.

In the text file I'm getting the name truncated with "..."

What can I add so that it doesn't truncate so that I can compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell outputs *objects*, not *text*.

If you want to output the file's names, then select the names and output them:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\PowerShell Tests\Group 1" -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
  Sort-Object -Unique |
  Out-File "C:\Powershell Tests\Group 1.txt"
```

Notes:

1. you don't need the subexpression operator, `$( )`, for the parameter to Get-ChildItem.
2. I removed your call to `Group-Object`. (It looked to me like you want a sorted list of unique file names.)

Comment: That works really well! New to Powershell so I'm still learning. I want to compare the text files and currently I'm using Compare-Object and I want to take the names in both text files and see the differences between the two. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: Look at the examples in `help Compare-Object -full`.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much sir!